# Does this property of the closure actually hold?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $F_1, F_2, F_3$ are three subsets of a metric space, does it have to be that $$\overline{F_1}\cap\overline{F_2}\cap\overline{F_3} = (\overline{F_1\cap F_2}\cap \overline{F_3}) \cup (\overline{F_1\cap F_3}\cap\overline{F_2})\cup (\overline{F_2\cap F_3}\cap\overline{F_1})? $$

I am trying to prove something, and in that setting I can only use intersections of closures of two sets, and not three, four, five etc. so I'm wondering if the above property holds, as then I could conclude that if $F_1\cap F_2\cap F_3 = \emptyset$ then $\overline{F_1}\cap\overline{F_2}\cap\overline{F_3} = \emptyset$ as well, and possibly generalize this approach to show that if $F_1\cap ..\cap F_n = \emptyset$ then $\overline{F_1}\cap ...\cap\overline{F_n} = \emptyset$ in my setting.

Comment: No, you could have three disjoint dense subsets. The right hand set would be empty, the left one the whole space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No take $X=\Bbb R$ and $F_1 = \Bbb Q$, $F_2 = \sqrt{2}\Bbb Q+\sqrt{3}$ and $F_3 = \sqrt{5}\Bbb Q + \sqrt{7}$. Then $\overline{F_1}\cap\overline{F_2}\cap\overline{F_3}= X$ while $(\overline{F_1\cap F_2}\cap \overline{F_3}) \cup (\overline{F_1\cap F_3}\cap\overline{F_2})\cup (\overline{F_2\cap F_3}\cap\overline{F_1}) = \emptyset$